# What's wrong with my insertion sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort a large datafile using an Insertion-based sorting algorithm, the code runs fine but the output is incorrect. I've studied it over and over to absolutely no avail, can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

```
public void sort(Comparable[] items) {
    for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        Comparable temp = items[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && items[j].compareTo(items[j]) > 0) {
            items[j + 1] = items[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        items[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

An example datafile I have produced is...

```
2
1
3
5
9
6
7
4
8
```

And obviously the output should be 1,2,3,4... - but instead I get 1
3
5
9
6
7
4
8
8

Comment: Can you show a sample test case that you are trying to sort?

Comment: Shouldn't it be items[j + 1] = temp?

Comment: and expected/actual output..

Comment: Why are you implementing the sort on your own? Is it part of an exercise? Or do you really just need to sort the datafile? If so consider the standard implementation of Sort

Comment: It's part of an excersie Lukas.

Answer (score 5):

`items[j].compareTo(items[j])` should be `items[j].compareTo(temp)`, otherwise you're just comparing the item against itself - you need to be comparing it against the object you want to insert.

Then `items[j] = temp;` will also cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because, at the end of the loop, `items[j]` is smaller than `temp`, or `j == -1`, so we need to insert at the position after that - the simplest fix is just changing that to `items[j+1] = temp;`.

Comment: Hi Dukeling, thanks for the help. The output is still incorrect though. It outputs...2 1 3 5 9 6 7 4 8 now.

Answer (score 0):

[**Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

```java
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
```

**Translated to Java:**

```
import java.util.*;

class InsertionSortTest {
    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while (j > 0 && A[j-1] > A[j]) {
                int t = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j-1];
                A[j-1] = t;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 5, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4 };

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(insertionSort(arr)));
    }
}
```